# Deferred JOIN: can't handle JOIN USING without authoritative tables

Tags: mysql, prisma, planetscale

I have a basic database in which I'm trying to implement the [deferred join technique](https://planetscale.com/courses/mysql-for-developers/examples/deferred-joins). However, on Planetscale I keep getting the following error: `can't handle JOIN USING without authoritative tables`.

I'm not terribly well-versed in MYSQL, but I'm struggling to understand what might be the issue. Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM Story ORDER BY createdAt,id LIMIT 20 OFFSET xxx
) dummy USING (id)
ORDER BY
  createdAt,id;
```

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default              | Extra             |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
| id        | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI |                      | auto_increment    |
| title     | varchar(255)    | NO   | MUL |                      |                   |
| synopsis  | varchar(2048)   | NO   |     |                      |                   |
| createdAt | datetime(3)     | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| updatedAt | datetime(3)     | YES  |     |                      |                   |
| content   | mediumtext      | NO   | MUL |                      |                   |
| wordcount | int             | NO   |     |                      |                   |
| authorId  | int             | NO   | MUL |                      |                   |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
```

update, to add `show create table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Articles` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `synopsis` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updatedAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `wordcount` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `authorId` int DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  KEY `Story_authorId_idx`(`authorId`), 
  KEY `Story_createdAt_idx`(`createdAt`), 
  KEY `createdAt`(`createdAt`), 
  FULLTEXT KEY `Story_title_content_synopsis_idx`(`title`, `content`, `synopsis`), 
  FULLTEXT KEY `Story_title_idx`(`title`), 
  FULLTEXT KEY `Story_content_idx`(`content`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 7892518284260113982 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I originally generated the schema via Prisma (if that matters), but have since written things/queries natively because of performance issues.

Comment: sounds like planetscale is only sort of mysql-compatible?  or is this error coming from whatever you are using to run the query, not server side?  you could try making it `select Articles.* from Articles inner join (select id,createdAt from...) dummy on Articles.id=dummy.id order by dummy.createdAt, dummy.id`

Comment: @ysth PlanetScale uses a proxy to parse SQL and direct it to the shard(s) that hold the data needed by that query. It will approach, but never fully reach 100% compatibility with MySQL's syntax.

Comment: @ysth - yeah the error comes via their CLI tool. The syntax you provide works great (thanks!). I'm just a little baffled now b/c the query I posted comes from their site (w/ my table of course)

Comment: Maybe you have an old version?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: How is the table sharded?  That is, on what key?

Comment: @RickJames unfortunately I don't know.  If there's a way to see i can try it out, though I suspect it might be some of the "magic" that's taken care of for you.  I also added the `show create table` if it's helpful

Comment: @wes - For the task, the query and the schema are excellent.  (Bill found the Answer to the actual Question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try rewriting your query to the equivalent `ON <expression>` syntax.

This:

```
FROM Articles JOIN ( ...) AS dummy USING (id)
```

Can be written as:

```
FROM Articles JOIN ( ...) AS dummy ON Articles.id = dummy.id
```

There is special behavior in SQL for `SELECT *` when you have the `USING` syntax. The `*` wildcard expands to all columns, but columns that are known to be equal are included in the result set only once.

I have not tested this with PlanetScale, so I don't know if PlanetScale will handle it or not.

This issue claims that `USING` is supported since May 2022:  https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/pull/10226 But I didn't find anything in the release notes since that date describing the feature. You may have more luck if you search more thoroughly.

Comment: so - yes, that works! Thanks you (also - now baffled b/c the code snippet comes directly from planetscale's site)

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a tech support call to PlanetScale.

Comment: I came across the same issue today (thanks!) and this fixed the syntax but weirdly, when adding the inner join, I no longer get any rows back.
I suspect it's due to the presence of a where clause in the outer query but I can't find any examples of how to deal with where clauses when using this approach. Do you happen to have any examples?

Comment: @RossCoundon Sorry, I don't answer questions on Stack Overflow anymore. I suggest you post a new question and be sure to [include a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - don't make people guess at your query or your table and columns.

Comment: No problem, was more of a general question about whether there were any examples of how to implement a WHERE clause with this method floating around. Seems it needs to be on the inner join query, not the outer